# Variable not defined. How do i define it?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
p=3.14159

#Function to circleArea
def circleArea(A):
    A=r*r*p
    radius=r
    return radius

#Main Program
r=int(input("Enter radius: "))
print("The area of the circle is:" )
print(circleArea(A))
```

Why does the line beneath yield this error?

```
print(circleArea(A))
```

> NameError: name 'A' is not defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you want to return `r*r*p` from `circleArea()` function and pass `r` as an argument. Also, you may want to use [math.pi](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.pi) instead of hardcoding it's value:

```
import math

#Function to circleArea
def circleArea(r):
    return r * r * math.pi

#Main Program
r=int(input("Enter radius: "))
print("The area of the circle is:" )
print(circleArea(r))
```

DEMO:

```
Enter radius: 10
The area of the circle is:
314.159265359
```

Comment: what is ment by import math?

Comment: `math` is a module from python's standard lib, `math.pi` is used in the code - that's why it's imported.

Comment: ok i'm new with python just started learning it

Answer (score 4):

In your function definition, `A` is just a local variable *inside* the function. The variable that you're wanting to pass in is actually called `r`. So, instead, you want:

```
print(circleArea(r))
```

You also want to change your function declaration to:

```
def circleArea(r):
```

Comment: Enter radius: 5
The area of the circle is:
5 it didn't work

Comment: @user2758724 Look at your code... your `circleArea` function is calculating the area but never using it. It's just returning the radius it was given. You probably want `return A` ("return the area I just calculated")

Comment: @user2758724 That's because the code inside your function is wrong as well. I thought helping you with passing the variable would give you a  kickstart; I didn't realise you wanted me to write all of your code for you. If you look at your function you'll quite plainly see that you pass `r` and, assign `A` and then just return `r` without ever changing it. Maybe you need to go back to basics.

Comment: OK, I'M New with python so i don't really know how it works

Comment: It's not how python works. It's lack of understanding, what You are trying to accomplish. Spend some time to get what your own code is , and what is supposed to do.